# How to make a proper footer so that when the webpage is zoomed in, the elements will go accordingly

Tags: html, css

I am making a footer for our project. How do I make it so that when I zoom in the webpage, the "Follow us on Facebook" will go on top of the footer info? I am sorry for some mistakes that you may find in my code. Suggestions and corrections will greatly appreciated.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title> Pamana Beach Resort </title>
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icon.png">
          <style>
          div#fixedfooter {
            position:fixed;
            bottom:0px;
            left: 0px;
            width:100%;
            height: 70px;
            background:#00ADEF;
          }
          #footer-info {
            background-color: #00adef;
            width: 50%;
            margin-left: 50px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            float: left;
          }

          #footer-infotext {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-family: footer-info;
            font-size: 90%;

            text-align: center;
            float: left;
          }
          #social {
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-right: 30px;
            background-color: #00adef;
            float: right;
            widht: 400px;

          }
          #sociallogo {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
          }
          #socialtext {
            float:left;
            font-family: footer-info;
            padding-right: 10px;
            color: #FFFFFF;
          }


          @font-face {
              font-family: footer-info;
              src: url(GOTHIC.ttf);
          }
          @font-face {
              font-family: footer-infoBold;
              src: url(GOTHICB.ttf);
          }

          #bold-info {
            font-family: footer-infoBold;
            font-size: 100%;
          }

        </style>
      </head>

      <footer>
        <div id="fixedfooter" >
          <div id="footer-info">
              <p id="footer-infotext">Designed by <span id="bold-info">CMSC 2 Students | Pamana Beach Resort </span> © Copyright 2016, All Rights Reserved.</p>
          </div>
          <div id="social">
              <p id="socialtext">FOLLOW US ON FACEBOOK</p>
              <img id="sociallogo" src="social.png">
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Major points:

- Close your tags! You didn’t close your footer and some div-elements.
- Put the “social”-div first, so it gets on top when the view gets
  smaller.
- From the id “fixedfooter” delete the “height” attribute.
  Otherwise, the footer will not be big enough to show all the info on
  small screens.
- Use @media to change your code according to the screen-size.

Please look at the code snippet below to see all the changes. I hope it helps.

```css
* {} #fixedfooter {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: #00ADEF;
  text-align: center;
}
#footer-info {
  background-color: #00adef;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#footer-infotext {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: footer-info;
  font-size: 90%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
#social {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #00adef;
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#sociallogo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
#socialtext {
  float: left;
  font-family: footer-info;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: footer-info;
  src: url(GOTHIC.ttf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: footer-infoBold;
  src: url(GOTHICB.ttf);
}
#bold-info {
  font-family: footer-infoBold;
  font-size: 100%;
}
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  #footer-info {
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  #social {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Pamana Beach Resort</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icon.png">
</head>

<body>

  <footer>
    <div id="fixedfooter">
      <div id="social">
        <p id="socialtext">FOLLOW US ON FACEBOOK</p>
      </div>
      <div id="footer-info">
        <p id="footer-infotext">Designed by <span id="bold-info">CMSC 2 Students | Pamana Beach Resort </span> © Copyright 2016, All Rights Reserved.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But how do I make it so that when it is zoomed, all elements are in the center?

Comment: I've updated the code above. You can use "margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;" to center objects. Unfortunately, I'm running out of time to complete it but you should get the general idea how to do this now. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to place your "Follow us on facebook" on top of your other element and float it right at high resolutions. I've created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zq2qj2xg/) to demonstrate it. However you might need to adjust the resolution breakpoint in the `@media` query to fit your needs.

Comment: What happens is the other element disappears when I zoomed in